# Can you buy bitcoins as a Canadian without a bank account?

Tags: bitcoin-credit-card

So is it 100% true that one cannot but bitcoins with just a credit card BUT your purchase MUST be connected to a bank account?  If it's supposed go be anonymous then why is the bank account needed? I just want to try owning $10 worth of bitcoins by buying with a credit card...is that possible?

Comment: One of these will probably be both available to you and  anonymous. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_Bitcoins_(the_newbie_version)

Comment: Try local bitcoins. They allow you to find someone in your area and you can buy with cash (but you will pay a ~10% premium for this).

Answer (score 1):

There's a [wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_To_Buy_Bitcoins_With_Your_Credit_Card) page about buying Bitcoins with a credit card. It seems the ideal options for you would be [Brawker](https://brawker.com/) or [MeetPays](https://www.meetpays.com/). But whatever method you decide to use, don't forget that Bitcoin is not anonymous (by default), that's a common myth.

Comment: Hmmm...why is it not anonymous by default?  Have you used MeetPay or Brawker? Are 100% legitimate?

Comment: It is not anonymous if you use it carelessly (without mixing your coins), because the Blockchain is a public ledger and anybody can connect the dots and trace the coins. Your anonymity is blown at the instant you make a transaction that is connected with you real-life person. That obviously includes buying coins via a service that knows your identity, which is the case with all credit card purchases. And no, I haven't used MeetPay nor Brawker, but the best way to find out is try with a small amount.

Answer (score 0):

Bank accounts, or any accounts or registration or identification whatsoever, are by No means connected to Bitcoin in any way.

The "connected to bank account" stuff is only where fiat money ($ or €) is involved.

Reason you can't pay with credit card (which is also connected to your bank account by the way) is that credit card payments can be reversed even months after the purchase, whereas Bitcoin transactions cannot. Same problem with paypal. This makes credit cards and paypal extremely risky payment options for merchants or sellers.

The usual procedure is: you buy bitcoins online, usually by sending $ or € to an exchange, convert it to ฿ (at this point it's still in some account at the exchange that's connected to you). Get the ฿ out (to your own wallet), mix it through some other wallets if you're really paranoid (really not necessary, just saying) and now nothing is connected to those bitcoins at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can buy bitcoins without a bank account. Unfortunately, you will most likely not be able to buy from an exchange. And I don't think you can buy with a credit card anywhere(though I am not sure about this statement).  Your option is to buy directly from someone you know who has BTC or you can trade with someone in exchange for prepaid cards or something similar.

My favorite way is to do a cash deposit in exchange for bitcoins. Cash deposit is one of the most secure form of payment for a seller and it is relatively easy for you. It requires no identification or bank account.

Comment: Mathieu, please do not try to make trades using this site. We don't want users getting harmed because random internet guy on Stack Exchange said to send them a money.